# Does anyone know the URL that Microsoft Tag Reader hits?

Tags: url, microsoft-tag

This is in reference to the Microsoft Tag barcodes (color).

Does anyone have the landing url and correct querystring format that the reader hits to then redirect to the looked up URL.  I have manually decoded a tag and I also generated my own tag but I wanted to know the URL that is the tag handler.

The hex in my tag file:
1560652D9BC2DC614D7C8FC711B

The actual barcode data:
60652D9BC2DC614D7C8FC711B

What I am wanting is the correct url something like:
http://something.something.com?code=60652D9BC2DC614D7C8FC711B

I wanted to manually paste the url into a browser and then append the hex code of the tags to test them since I can't find any tag reader for a win desktop.  I don't personally own a smart phone (yea, I know, I am a dinosaur sometimes) so I can't simply print and scan.

I poked around in one of the readers for Win6.2 mobi and found some URLs but I don't have the correct format of the query strings nor do I know which one is the correct url for the tag handler.

TIA,
Wolfie

Comment: @Wolfire: How did you manually decoded tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the tag on [tag.microsoft.com](http://tag.microsoft.com/) the url looks like this before redirecting:

> http://rs.tag.microsoft.com/CABJLI4W6GS5WSCAWVMH72ABZ2XRHG4I.aspx?Level=1&VID=1%2B89%2B3&afid=0&TH=_OxhkqW8E01uhOwWheA%24&CS=U8&PL=qrQE2SMsRQVDmPwsDgQ8Bp38owXtqzy9FB5EFiP91BM_SCd7j%2BXEXbTOZ9BMIDFyVfTGGSNDVn6d7c8ktswRyy9WSgI8lN0FWVg6Bu6DwErCoWrAMyBAcljvoGJSX08a_vDIRtawDaJDQVx2WvakfyNUNwfq8MdWxNBz2UpLOBZB5tQJQVFefeCa1le9tQW5TTslcCCc1nVVWVgLmOfDO8ahGqZLN191SZq6eColLmyZmN0iy6UGr0ItTHxegsgUTzFfHYSLsDu2rhu3NiNJclP50RBbMF4Dh4ixXg%24%24

It points to [this page](http://mobile.microsoft.com/tag/about/generaltag.mspx). And I guess it's a little more complicated than you thought? :)

I scanned the tag with my phone and quickly selected the url and copy/pasted it before the browser was redirected to the destination page.

But I have to admit, I'm not sure I understand your scenario? Why do you want to use the (very complicated) url the Tag Reader redirection service uses? The mobile browser will ultimately end up on your site (as you configured it in the Tag Manager) and the only dynamic thing in the url, would be the device ID. And that's pretty easy to mock/fake for your own testing purposes.

Comment: Because, as I said, at the time I didn't have a smartphone to scan the tag to test with.